# UV Unwrap a "fragmented" mesh

Tags: mesh, uv

I have a mesh which is a collection of meshes with distinct geometry. It is the object on the left of the picture.

[image: Object on the left had "broken" UVs]

When I UV unwrap it, blender places the distinct meshes on a "grid" and "projects" those surfaces on the texture. The problem is that the meshe's parts are not in the correct position relative to eachother.

[image: Broken UV unwrap]

On the right object of the first picture, there is no partition on the mesh and the UV unwraps properly. How can I achieve the UV results of the object to the right for the object to the left?

Comment: In this particular case, a simple "Project from view" (with the view set like in your first picture) should do the job.

Comment: Thanks @thibsert, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try project from view or place the uv islands manually to match the grid!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM

check this video for more info.

Comment: A screenshot(s)/video illustrating the other option would be nice.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y7M-B6xnaEM 
Here :D

Comment: It is in the video at 4:06.